# Plot graph with values of vectors

Tags: r, plot, vector, graph

I want to visualize the elements of my vectors in a graph. I want to generate a graph with a certain x- and y-axis and then put the values of my vectors as points into the graph. I also want different colors for the values of the different vectors. How do I do that?

For example: I have 10 elements in vector A and want to put those elements into the graph. The first Element of vector A has the y-value A[1] and the x-value 1. The second Element of vector A has the y-value A[2] and the x-value 2. Same with vector B.

```
vec1 = 1:10
vec2 = 1:10
for(idx in 1:10){
  vec1[idx] = runif(1, min=0, max=100)
  vec2[idx] = runif(1, min=0, max=100)
}
plot(vec1 and vec2) // How do I do this?
```

dput output for vec1: `c(81.9624423747882, 45.583715592511, 56.2400584807619, 8.25600677635521,  82.0227505406365, 45.6240070518106, 68.7916911672801, 94.491201499477,  22.0095717580989, 4.29550902917981)`

dput output for vec2: `c(29.5684755546972, 68.0154771078378, 52.2058120695874, 2.48502977192402,  91.9532125117257, 24.7736480785534, 66.5003522532061, 79.014728218317,  47.9641782585531, 20.5593338003382)`

Comment: What have you tried? What’s wrong with just `plot(A)`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I want multiple vectors visualized in one graph. I don't know how to do that because `plot(vec)` only plots on vector.

Comment: Please read the documentation and the examples provided there, it contains code to do exactly that.

Comment: Hi @abcdefghi019283, could you please add a minimal reproducible example. If you're not sure how to do this, you have check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). A simplified version of your data and what you have tried already would do.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Do you have a link for the documentation or those examples. I did not find anything helpful.

Comment: @abcdefghi019283 Post the output of `dput(A)` and be a bit more detailed in describing what you want, i.e. just points, or points with arrows, or points with connecting lines.

Comment: @IRTFM I added the dput information but I don't quite understand why you would need them. As I said in the opening post: Just simple points. No arrows, no connecting lines just the simple values of two vectors plotted into the same graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with

```
vec1 = 1:10
vec2 = 1:10
for(idx in 1:10){
  vec1[idx] = runif(1, min=0, max=100)
  vec2[idx] = runif(1, min=0, max=100)
}
plot(vec1 and vec2) // How do I do this?
```

Try this:

```
plot( 1:20, c(vec1,vec2) , col=rep(1:2,10)  # just points
lines( 1:20, c(vec1,vec2) )                 # add lines
# if you wanted the same x's for both sequences the first argument could be 
#      rep(1:10, 2)  instead of 1:20
```

Note: Your set up code could have been just two lines (no loop):

```
  vec1 = runif(10, min=0, max=100)
  vec2 = runif(10, min=0, max=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest is to create a data frame, which is usually what most functions expect in R:

```
library(tidyverse)

vec1 = 1:10
vec2 = 1:10
for(idx in 1:10){
  vec1[idx] = runif(1, min=0, max=100)
  vec2[idx] = runif(1, min=0, max=100)
}


df <- data.frame(order = 1:10, vec1, vec2) %>%
  pivot_longer(!order, names_to = "color", values_to = "value")

plot(df$order, df$value,  col = c("red","blue")[df$color %>% as.factor()])
```

[image]

Comment: I see what you're saying @Konrad Rudolph, if I understood correctly after re-reading the question, I believe that's what the second part of my answer was doing (altough I did call it `order`). I edited the answer to keep just that. Or maybe am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering or guessing whether you are aiming for the facility provided by teh base-plotting function arrows? This is the example in the ?arrows page:

```
 x <- stats::runif(12); y <- stats::rnorm(12)
 i <- order(x, y); x <- x[i]; y <- y[i]
 plot(x,y, main = "arrows(.)" )
 ## draw arrows from point to point :
 s <- seq(length(x)-1)  # one shorter than data
 arrows(x[s], y[s], x[s+1], y[s+1], col = 1:3)
```

If you wanted instead to plot with each vector (represented by "arrows") starting from the origin it would be:

```
x <- stats::runif(12); y <- stats::rnorm(12)
# ordering not needed this time
plot(x,y, main = "arrows(.)", xlim=c(0, max(x)) # to let origin be seen)
## draw arrows from origin to point :
s <- length(x)  # one shorter than data
arrows(rep(0,s), rep(0,s), x, y, col = 1:3)
```

[image]

Comment: No, I just want to plot each value of each vector in one single graph. No arrows or means, just the simple values. `plot(vec)` does the job for one vector. But I have two vectors and I don't know how I get those values into the same graph.